# ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 1000000 bytes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

/*
Write a function to insert the string in a table which will display the character of string
If You enter Sameer then output will be

s

a

m

e

e

r

*/

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(c in varchar2)
                  return varchar2
is
a number := 0;
b varchar2(20);
var_len number := length(c); 
begin
     loop
         a := a + 1;
         if a <= var_len then
        select SUBSTR(c, a,1) into b from dual;
           end if;
           dbms_output.put_line(b);

    END LOOP;
               return b;
END;
```

--I written the error below

/*

```
ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 1000000 bytes
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 32
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 97
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 112
ORA-06512: at "ADWHS.F1", line 13
20000. 00000 -  "%s"
*Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
           was called which causes this error to be generated.
*Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
           the application administrator or DBA for more information.
```

*/

Comment: use "set SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 10000000;" or "SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED;" if you are using newer version of oracle

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer  Version:21.4.3.063.0100

Comment: Do not *set serveroutput...*. The error you  are getting is **not the problem**, it is your friend. The problem is that your loop **has no exit condition**. It will continue looping and printing (to dbms_output buffer) the last letter of your input string until the loop control variable  `a`  exceeds its maximum possible value (or all memory (disk?)) is filled. Change your `IF` statement to `exit when a > var_len`.   See [LOOP and EXIT statements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/controlstructures.htm#i8296).